# Ninja-IDE virtualenv not importing

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, ide, virtualenv

I started a new project in the Ninja-IDE and assigned it to a virtualenv folder in the settings.

The virtualenv works fine in the terminal, but Ninja-IDE doesn't recognize the packages in it and throws an import error.

How can I access the packages in the virtualenv in Ninja-IDE?

Thanks!

- Ubuntu
- Python 2.7
- Through VirtualBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick answer so that others may find it useful. I had a very similar problem a little while ago, and had a lot of trouble finding a quick workable solution anywhere, not even google.

I somehow figured out that the solution was to simply create a virtualenv folder with the version of numpy I wanted, and then pointed the "virtualenv" property for NinjaIDE project to that folder. I restarted NinjaIDE and boom, instantly worked.

To set the virtualenv property for your project via the GUI, go to the Project menu:

```
Project > Open Project Properties > Project Execution
```

and you should see a variable called "Virtualenv Folder". Point that to the folder for your virtualenv, and it should work. (May need to restart NinjaIDE.)

> This worked for me, NinjaIDE version 2.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.

Edit by asker: If the above doesn't fix the problem, try PyCharm-- it works for me.